# Could someone help me with the button in javascript displaying paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to create a button that changes the paragraph from visible to invinsible and the opposite but i cannot get it to work.

```css
p1 {
 
 display = none;
 
 }


button {
 position:absolute;
 background-color: #8C6D09;
 color: white;
 padding: 16px 32px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin:4px 2px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s; 
 }
 
button1{
 background-color:#8C6D09;
 color:#FFF;
 position:absolute;
 }
  
  p1 {
 
 display = none;
 
 }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div id="p1">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <div>
   
    <script>
 function toggle_visibility(id){
  var p = document.getElementById(id)
   if(p1.style.display == "block")
   p1.style.display = "none";
   else
   p1.style.display = "block";
  }

    
    </script>
<button class="button button1"onclick="toggle_visibility"("p1")>Easy</button>
    </body>
     </html>
```

sorry for adding p1 in css twice it's actually only added once in the original code

Comment: Thems are some messed up quotes there. It's supposed to be `onclick="toggle_visibility('p1')"`.

Comment: Here is a working jsFiddle for you:

    https://jsfiddle.net/dtqxabof/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.

To access the `id` of `p1` you need to use a hash symbol:

```
#p1 {
    display:none;
}
```

Same with your buttons, to access the classes, you'll use a dot:

```
.button {
    ...your styles
}
```

Your HTML is also wrong:

```
<button class="button button1"onclick="toggle_visibility"("p1")>Easy</button>
```

should be:

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="toggle_visibility('p1')">Easy</button>
```

Comment: i have made those changes but the text "hello" still appears right above the button and now whenever i press the button twice both the button and text disappear and never come back

Comment: Turns out it was a stupid mistake it works now  thanks alot guys

Comment: Do tick the answer if it helped...

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code. Here is the working snippet:

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var p = document.getElementById(id)
  if(p.style.display == "block") {
    p.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    p.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#p1 {
  display: none;
}


button {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #8C6D09;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s; 
}
 
#button1 {
  background-color:#8C6D09;
  color:#FFF;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="p1">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<button class="button button1" onclick="toggle_visibility('p1')">Easy</button>
```

Look it through and notice differences.